# How can i pass an HTML5 canvas' data to the controller of the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html5-canvas

Is there a way to get the canvas' data from this view...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/digisig.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
    {
        <canvas id="digisigBox" width="400" height="200">

        </canvas>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

...to this controller?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Typically I use the FormCollection.AllKeys to get the data but I've not worked much with canvases and I can't seem to find anything on passing the canvas' data to the controller in MVC.

Comment: You can use the `toDataURL` method of the canvas element to get the image data ... and then you can POST it to your controller by f.e. inserting it into a hidden form field.

Comment: OK, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toDataURL` method of the canvas element to get the image data - and then you can POST it to your controller by f.e. inserting it into a hidden form field.

Comment: CBroe can you explain it more? i'm also having this problem

Comment: @Reynan: Well what exactly is your problem? Have you looked up the mentioned method on the web?